# C# - animation using Graphics.DrawImage

Tags: c#, image

I am animating a moving image on a computer with a resolution of 1920 x 1080.

When I run the same program on a computer with a smaller resolution, image is moving very quickly, and when I use a bigger resolution, it is moving slowly:

My code:

```
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics kp = e.Graphics;
        kp.DrawImage(image, point.X, point.Y, width, height);
    }

    private void timer_move_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        point.X += 5;
        Refresh();
    }
```

How can I fix it?

EDIT:

Image size is calculated by resolution of screen.

EDIT 2:

I have more pictures here and one of these pictures are every timer_move_Tick smaller.

Code:

```
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics kp = e.Graphics;
        kp.DrawImage(image, point.X, point.Y, width, height);
        kp.DrawImage(image2, point2.X, point2.Y, width2, height2);
    }

    private void timer_move_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        point.X += 5;
        width2 -= 1; /*This is the problem*/
        height2 -= Convert.ToInt32(percent_width / 9);
        point2.Y -= Convert.ToInt32(percent_width / 2);
        Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: Try to move image border instead, and redraw it only after moving is finished.

Comment: How large is the image? (@athabaska: I doubt that this is the point of the animation)

Comment: oh, bad reading skills on my side

Comment: Your image is supposed to shrink at each tick of the timer?

Comment: My image is moving to horizont so I'd like to shrink it. It isn't must be at each tick of timer.

Comment: Well, you can't do that at each tick because it will eventually disappear, unless the timer has a limit. I'm guessing that `height2 -= Convert.ToInt32(percent_width / 9);` should be somewhere else, maybe inside the `form_paint`, before the `Drawimage`

Comment: @chiapa Problem is with width2.

Comment: Try moving that line to the `form_paint`, before the `Drawimage`

Comment: Man, what exactly do you want to do with that image? Shrink it? How much? And how? Is the `height` line correct? Please be clearer so I can help you. Also, your English isn't very good and that's not helping. Can you speak another language in which you express yourself better?

Comment: In this application I'm firing torpedos. This torpedos are moving up on the screen (retire). So I'd like to be realistics in the game and shrink torpedos. Do you know what I mean? Height line is correct. I can speak Czech.

Comment: Sorry, no Czech for me. Anyway, you mean to make the torpedoes thinner as they go up? So it looks like they are going far from the shooter? If `width` is a `float` and not an `int`, you can decrease it by smaller values, like `0.05` or something

Comment: rád, že být užitečné! Good luck with your game

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your `timer_move_tick` function, the value you add to the `point.X` must be a percentage (or relative to the screen size) one. That way the image will move at the same speed no matter what resolution you have.

After your edit: if the image size is calculated regarding the screen resolution, the incremented value to `point.X` must also be related to it. If it is, you will get the same behavior for the image.

Comment: This work, but what when I have size (of image) -= 1

Comment: I'm sorry, could you explain better? What do you mean?

Comment: "height -= 1" I can't use your variant for it.

Comment: You will have to post some more code as I don't know where that comes from. Besides, what has the image height to do with its movement?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Screen.Bounds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.bounds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the resolution information:

```
var screenResolution = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size;
var relativeSpeed = 0.01;
var horizontalSpeed = screenResolution.Width * relativeSpeed;
```

Also, several remarks:

1. Use `Invalidate()` instead of `Refresh()` in your `Tick` handler.
2. To get flicker-free animation, make sure that you configure `ControlStyles` flags in your constructor properly:

   ```
   public MainForm()
   {
       InitializeComponent();

       SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | 
           ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | 
           ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw |
           ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
   }
   ```